# System.Windows.Controls.TextBox Handle

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, textbox

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

I know that forms in general have a `Handle` property, but I am using a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` and it does not have a `Handle` property.

How do I access the `TextBox`'s handle? I noticed that `RichTextBox` has the Handle property, so why not the regular `TextBox`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>You can just call [Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) on the TextBox.  It is an inherited property from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.</strike>

**Edit: Question was updated to ask about WPF**

WPF doesn't use handles like a typical Win32 application or WinForms application.  Each control is not its own Window in WPF.  You can verify this with Spy++, it cannot differentiate between each control.  Therefore you cannot SendMessage to the individual controls like you can with WinForms and Win32 apps.

You can use [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) to get the parent window handle of a WPF window.

Comment: @Brian sorry. I posted wrong. I have fixed the post, and now you can see it does not inherit from System.Windows.Forms at all. It is a WPF textbox

Comment: @Darkhydro: Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @Brian What?! So then how do I use native Windows messaging protocols with WPF forms..? If I can't get the handle I can't use any of that stuff.

Comment: @Darkhydro: You'll just have to use other types of inter process communication.

Comment: You can also host a winforms control inside a WPF app if that helps.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. That clears things up quite a bit, although i'm not exactly happy with the answer.

Comment: I added one more comment that may help you.

Comment: @Brian I'm already hosting the WPF form inside a Windows Forms form. I'm not going to further complicated things >_< . I accomplished what I was trying to do by other means.