# How to enable text box to contain default value and be able to edit it in WP8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm scanning a document and saving three values.

I want to create a pop-up that will appear after the scan and will consist of 3 text boxes. Each text box will contain by default the scanned value, when I will have the abuilty to edit it by pressing on the text box.

I've looked at the text box properties but found only "read-only" property.
Besides that, I really don't have a clue how to start and what to look for.

meanwhile I have this xaml  describing the pop-up:

```
<Popup x:Name="AfterScan" Grid.Row="2">
    <Border  BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
        <StackPanel Background="Gainsboro" Width="434" Height="400">
            <TextBlock Text="Bill Details" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Margin="10,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Please review Bill Details and click OK when done" FontSize="17" Margin="40,0,10,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
                <TextBox x:Name="test"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
                <TextBox x:Name="test2"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
                <Button x:Name="btn_OK"  Content="OK" Width="215" Margin="110,0,10,0" Click="EnsuredDetails_Click" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black"/> 
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

I know that If I write a value - I can get it and use it later, but I want the text box to contain my scanned value.

I also saw this article:
http://mrbool.com/how-to-build-a-custom-textbox-in-windows-phone/25846

My problem is that the default value of this text box is a string declared in the  xaml code, and I need it to be a dynamic parameter:

```
 <my:DefaultTxt_box Height="103" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-4,49,0,0"Name="defaultTxt_box1"
                           Text="" D_Text="Enter Your Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460"FontSize="32" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#FFFFFF4C">
            <my:DefaultTxt_box.Background>
```

Can someone please guide me a little?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're not using data binding, you can just do `test.Text = "Default Value"` (where `test` represents the `x:Name` you assigned the text box).

Comment: but then "default value" is a constant string. I need it each time to be different vlaue

Comment: You'll need to use C# to set the text value or a binding. You can't do it from Xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to options to get this done.

**Option 1)**

You can bind text property of textbox with dynamic value property. for this you can use [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx) link.

**Option 2)**

You will have three textboxes in xaml of popup.

```
<TextBox x:Name="test"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" Text="your default value will go here"/>

<TextBox x:Name="test_2"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" Text="your default value will go here"/>

<TextBox x:Name="test_3"  Width="100" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" Text="your default value will go here"/>
```

Then you can set text property of text boxes from code behind c# code. For this, first you have to get value out from scanned document.

Suppose you have got these values in variables ScannedValue1, ScannedValue2 and ScannedValue3

```
String ScannedValue1 ; //You will have to assigned values from scanned copy here
String ScannedValue2 ; //You will have to assigned values from scanned copy here
String ScannedValue3 ; //You will have to assigned values from scanned copy here
```

Then you can utilize these values to assign them to text boxes of pop up.

```
test.Text = ScannedValue1;
test_2.Text = ScannedValue2;
test_3.Text = ScannedValue3;
```

Hope you can get idea from this :)

Comment: Thanks, but again in the second option , the default value is set to a string that I enter. I want it to be different each time.

Comment: For that you have to set values in ScannedValue1, ScannedValue2 and ScannedValue3 from scanned document.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
Textbox myTxtbx = new Textbox();
myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";

myTxtbx.OnFocus += OnFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);
myTxtbx.LoseFocus += LoseFocus.EventHandle(AddText);

public RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myTxtbx.Text = "";
}

public AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(myTxtbx.Text == "")
        myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";
}
```

[Adding placeholder text to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873378/adding-placeholder-text-to-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Every textBox should have a x:Name property, and just set it in your C# code like this:

```
myTextBox.Text = 'myScannedValue';
```

'myTextBox' is your x:Name of TextBoxin XAML. try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use PhoneTextBox from Windows Phone Toolkit. http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-phonetextbox-in-depth