# Can't set placeholder on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a placeholder on `TextBox`, I don't know why Microsoft doesn't provide a default property for this control, is very annoying apply a workaround. Anyway, suppose that I've this control:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Search" />
```

I've created a separate class to handle all control event. This is the method inside it:

```
class ControlsHandle
{
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(); 

    public void RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        main.Search.Text = "";
    }

    public void AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(main.Search.Text))
            main.Search.Text = "Search a user...";
    }
}
```

and this is the `MainWindow()`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Search.GotFocus += GotFocus.EventHandle(ControlsHandle.RemoveText);
    Search.LostFocus += LostFocus.EventHandle(ControlsHandle.AddText);
}
```

Unfortunately I got this error:

> the UIElement.GotFocus event cannot be specified only on the left side of += or -=

on this line: `+= GotFocus.`

Comment: just simply add placeholder="Last name" or whatever.
placeholders are supported by the browser. You dont have to make any hacks to make it work.
Only old browser don't support it.
If you need to support old browsers, I would make javascript to support this.

Comment: <TextBox x:Name="Search" placeholder="Search a user..." />

Comment: @Kiksen this is wpf (xaml) not html. Xaml doesn't have a placeholder property

Comment: In that case this is a duplicate :) See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873378/adding-placeholder-text-to-textbox

Comment: You cannot convert a text box to placeholder. According to Microsoft behavior, a text box is one, which alters its own height and width when the text content in it is increased. Whereas a placeholder is a fixed one, it cannot change its size by itself when the text content in it is increased. Only user can be able to modify the width and size of the placeholder.

Comment: @ArunPrasad there is no placeholder property that I can use?

Comment: See solution of John Myczek: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: @SebastianSchulz too much code for a simple placeholder

Comment: there are some more solutions in the question

Comment: @Dillinger Try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873378/adding-placeholder-text-to-textbox/36909924#36909924

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`<TextBox Name="search" Text="Search a user..." GotFocus="search_GotFocus"/>`

```
 private void  search_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        search.Text = "";

    }
```