# How to add placeholder text to ToolStripTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip

In a WinForms project, I know how to add [placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22405509/9382) to a regular textbox.  But the ToolStripTextBox doesn't appear to be a regular textbox.  For one, it doesn't expose the handle (which is what's required to set the placeholder text via Win API).

So, how do I either set the placeholder text on a ToolStripTextBox or get its .Handle property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToolStripTextBox` hosts a [`ToolStripTextBoxControl`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/a.html#befa822b6f435863) inside which is derived from `TextBox` and you can access the the hosted control using its [`TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriptextbox.textbox.aspx) or its [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.control.aspx) property. So you can write such code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ToolStripTextBox))]
public class MyToolStripTextBox : ToolStripTextBox
{
    private const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg,
        int wParam, string lParam);
    public MyToolStripTextBox()
    {
        this.Control.HandleCreated += Control_HandleCreated;
    }
    private void Control_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cueBanner))
            UpdateCueBanner();
    }
    string cueBanner;
    public string CueBanner
    {
        get { return cueBanner; }
        set
        {
            cueBanner = value;
            UpdateCueBanner();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateCueBanner()
    {
        SendMessage(this.Control.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, cueBanner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also for a `TextBox`, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/3110834) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36534068/3110834).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Since it is not so easy (or I did not find an easy way to do) to replace the inner control, you can also use the SendMessage approach from outside: _ = NativeMethods.SendMessage(tstbSearch.TextBox.Handle, NativeMethods.EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, "Find...");

Comment: @TomB of course you can. What I've done in this post is creating a ready to use MyToolStripTextBox so that you can have the feature in design-time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried myself.

But the `Remarks` section indicates you can manipulate the `TextBox` control directly.

> ToolStripTextBox is the TextBox optimized for hosting in a ToolStrip. A subset of the hosted control's properties and events are exposed at the ToolStripTextBox level, **but the underlying TextBox control is fully accessible through the TextBox property**.

Answer (score 0):

to answer one of your questions

> "So, how do I either set the placeholder text on a ToolStripTextBox"

you may apply code below:

```
tspTextBox.TextBox.PasswordChar = Convert.ToChar("*");
```