# Winforms - cue banner text box issue in drop down item

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm attempting (for reasons) to use a cue banner textbox in place of the standard textbox in a WinForms dropdown item.

I've gotten it to a state where I can add the new control object to the list of dropdown options, but if I do, it locks up the properties menu for not only it, but also any other options on that same dropdown 'list'. It does not have this issue if I use it elsewhere in the form - just when its used in a dropdown.

I'm posting two pieces of code below:

1. My CueTextBox class (extend TextBox)
2. My ToolStripCueTextBox class (derive from ToolStripControlHost for designer availability)

   ```
   **//1 - Class for box**
   public class CueTextBox : TextBox
   {
       private string mCue;
       public string Cue
       {
           get => mCue;
           set
           {
               mCue = value;
               Invalidate();
           }
       }

       protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
       {
           base.WndProc(ref m);

           const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
           if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
           {
               if (!Focused && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Cue))
               {
                   using (var graphics = CreateGraphics())
                   {
                       TextRenderer.DrawText(
                           dc: graphics,
                           text: Cue,
                           font: Font,
                           bounds: ClientRectangle,
                           foreColor: SystemColors.GrayText,
                           backColor: Enabled ? BackColor : SystemColors.Control,
                           flags: TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left);
                   }
               }
           }
       } 

   **//2 - Class for toolstrip**
   [ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
   public class ToolStripCueTextBoxItem : ToolStripControlHost
   {
       public ToolStripCueTextBoxItem() : base(new CueTextBox())
       {
       }
   }
   ```

I'm new here, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [How to add placeholder text to ToolStripTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50918225/3110834)

Comment: Chasing this problem down isn't that useful, you'll have to throw away this code anyway.  TextBox is notorious for not using WM_PAINT consistently, a crime that goes back to 1980s hardware.  So you might as well [get it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/17034).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - I'm pretty sure I came across your work as I was tracking down potential solutions; thanks for pointing me to a more definitive solution.

Comment: The problem is not because of custom painting. Even if you host a normal `TextBox` in `ToolStripControlHost` without any custom paint logic the problem is still there. Try this for example `[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
 public class MyToolStripTextBox:ToolStripControlHost
 {
     public MyToolStripTextBox():base(new TextBox())
     {
     }
  }`

Comment: However in general since you want a single line text you don't need custom paint and you can send `EM_SETCUEBANNER` to `TextBox` of the standard `ToolStripTextBox` like the way suggested by Hans. In the first comment, you can find link to an implementation `ToolStripTextBox ` which shows cue banner based on  `EM_SETCUEBANNER` idea.

Comment: You can find [a post about a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8856394/3110834) with hosting a standard `MaskedTextBox` in toolstrip.

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei - hopefully I'll have time to try both approaches and get back with how each worked out for what I'm trying to do.