# Custom textBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

can anyone help me to creat a **textBox with the bottom border only in C#**? I'm using WinForms and .Net Framework 4.8. Here is the image that I want to create.
I need the correct solution for this.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? The idea is to have a Thickness of (0,0,0, borderThickness).

Comment: [This](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5507/how-to-customize-the-border-style-and-appearance-in-the-winforms-textboxext) can be helpful for you

Comment: I have tried 3-4 posts answer but none of them work for me.

Comment: @Mateech textBox does not contain a definition of BorderSides.

Comment: I don't want to use any Third-Party application or application extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to dock a label to bottom of TextBox like so

```
textBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
var label = new Label()
{
    Height = 1,
    Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
    BackColor = Color.Black
};
textBox1.Controls.Add(label);
```

Comment: Can you explain what does this line say: `public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;`

Comment: @TusharChaurasia It's for knowing if the left mousebutton is being pressed in the non-client area of the control (or form).

Answer (score 0):

This specific Textbox that you mentioned by showing a picture is called Material TextBox and such an UI is called Material UI.

You can refer this link:

[How to use material design controls c# winforms](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/441/how-to-use-material-design-controls-with-c-in-your-winforms-application)

The accepted answer will work perfectly fine however if you want something more professional, this could be your choice.

The link explains how to use the Nuget Package MaterialSkin.Updated in your winforms application to make a beautiful UI.

**EDIT :**

If you are not a coding geek and you need to do it without much coding part, you can create a simple user control with a textbox(design the backcolor and textcolour to suit your needs).

Then add a panel at the bottom with size (0,1) and set it to be visible only when the textbox gets focus.

This link provides examples to add placeholder to textboxes : [Placeholder StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873378/adding-placeholder-text-to-textbox)

Comment: Is that third party?

Comment: @TusharChaurasia: Exactly. It is a set of specially designed controls to enhance UI. Pls consult the link provided by me. It is a complete tutorial.

Comment: @D J  I do not want to use any Third -part library.

Comment: @TusharChaurasia: Oh. No problem. But an easy way is that you can create a user control with a textbox and a panel with size 0,1 and it gives the exact result. Read the **EDIT:** section. Don't forget to upvote if it works!

Comment: @TusharChaurasia: Yes. Adding code is always easier than creating usercontrols. However, it may be a secondary answer! Good luck!