# How to create TextBox handle in WPF Command Line application

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, textbox

I'm creating a WPF Command Line application.
Now the thing is that I use a DLL that converts sound to text. When I register the DLL, it wants a Handle to a TextBox, where it will then insert the text into.

How can I create such a virtual Handle, and then listen for any text inserts on it?

Comment: See this:

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054872/system-windows-controls-textbox-handle

Answer (score 0):

Part is the fact that I use WPF. WPF does not give out a Handle for every UI element. Instead, there's only one Handle for the window, and WPF handles all the drawing inside that window.

The second thing is that I use a command-line application that did not reference the proper PresentationCore and PresentationFoundation (WPF) or Forms (non-WPF), such that the TextBox did not exist.

Using System.Windows.Forms included the TextBox component that I could then instantiate and get the Handle from.

Now the remaining problem is that the 'textChanged' event does not seem to fire when the TextBox is not in the visual tree. But that's another question :-)