# C# TextBox.LineUp method

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a textbox in a typing tutor where, as users type, it will scroll as they reach the bottom of the textbox. I am trying to use the TextBox.LineUp() method, but I cannot get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
if (TText.LineCount > 3)
{
    TText.LineUp();
}
```

I have also tried LineDown(), just in case I'm thinking of this backwards, but neither works. I can find no documentation on this method.

EDIT:

```
private void Letter_Typed(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (TText.LineCount > 3)
    {
        ROText.LineUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean, you want it to create a scrollbar?
Is this winForms/WPF/MVC/ASP or something else?

Comment: It's WPF. No, I don't want a scrollbar (I don't think so, anyway). When I hover over the LineUp method, the tooltip says "Scrolls the content of the textbox up by one line." So I don't think I should need a scrollbar...

Comment: We need more code than that if we're to help! Are you sure control is even entering that `if`?

Comment: As Cameron points out, is this inside a textchanged event? or something similar

Comment: @Cameron I have added the whole method. I'm not sure what else you want? And yes, it is definitely hitting the LineUp method.

Comment: @AlexInTime it is on a PreviewTextInput event.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @Codor It is not scrolling the text up. It hits the method, but does nothing.

Comment: how about  textBox.ScrollToCaret(); UPDATE-> Scratch that, thats for winforms. and im guessing you have set "Multiline = True"?

Comment: @AlexInTime where do you find that? I do not have that option...

Comment: I do not have the Multiline property either...

Comment: Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: @Shaharyar I do not have quite enough reputation to share images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember a simiar situation where I finally ended up by using PInvoke as follows.

```
public static class TextBoxBaseExtensions
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, int wParam, Int32 lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);

    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;

    private const int SB_LINEUP = 0x00000;
    private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 0x00001;

    private const int SB_BOTTOM = 0x0007;
    private const int SB_TOP = 0x0006;

    public static void ScrollLineUp(this TextBoxBase iTextBoxBase)
    {
        SendMessage(iTextBoxBase.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0);
    }

    public static void ScrollLineDown(this TextBoxBase iTextBoxBase)
    {
        SendMessage(iTextBoxBase.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
    }

    public static void ScrollToBottom(this TextBoxBase iTextBoxBase)
    {
        SendMessage(iTextBoxBase.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);
    }

    public static void ScrollToTop(this TextBoxBase iTextBoxBase)
    {
        SendMessage(iTextBoxBase.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_TOP, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, Codor, I am not experienced enough to see how to integrate this into what I have? Where are you telling it to scroll down?

Comment: Add the class to your project, then make sure its namespace is accessible from your code. If done, there should be methods `ScrollToBottom` and `ScrollToTop` available for `TextBox`.

Comment: I will not be scrolling to the bottom (or top), though. I simply want it to scroll one line.

Comment: So in my case, should TextBoxBase be changed to TextBox, and then call it like: TextBoxBaseExtensions.ScrollLineUp(ROText);

Comment: Well sort of; in the .NET framework, `TextBoxBase` is the base class for both `TextBox` and `RichTextBox`, so using the type `TextBoxBase` will be just fine. The call will be `ScrollLineUp()` and will scroll exactly one line.

Comment: Ok, this is looking promising. One more question, am I correct that this uses System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase? Because I am calling it using my ROText textBox, which is a System.Windows.Controls.TextBox. Will this be OK?

Comment: I think it will be ok. Just try it.

Comment: I have tried it, and it gives an error: Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' to System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase'. How were you creating your textBox when you used this code?

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms? If not, try changing the type to the `TextBox` type you are using.

Comment: My textBox is a System.Windows.Controls TextBox. I have tried changing the type in your class, and the iTextBoxBase.Handle no longer works.

Comment: Apparently the handle can be obtained differently, as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054872/system-windows-controls-textbox-handle

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the working of `LineUp()`. It only perform scrolling when you have more lines than the `Height` of the `TextBox`.

**For Example 1:**

I have a textbox which can show only 2 lines at a time:

[image]

In this case `LineUp` will not work. Because you are not missing any lines.

**For Example 2:**

Now I write 3 lines in the textbox:

[image]

As you can see now I am missing the first one. Now `LineUp` works, when I click the button it scrolls to the first line:

[image]

This is how `LineUp` works.

**Important Note:**

In the last image as you can see that the `textbox` is not selected (or Focused). This method actually scrolls the textbox to show you the lines, it doesn't change the position of the **caret**.

If you expect it to change the caret's position. `LineUp` should not be your choice.

And it will not work if the target `textbox` is selected (or Focused).

Comment: I don't want it to change the caret's position. And it is missing some lines.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation the reason it could not be used is that there was not a line of text below where it was when it was currently wanting to go down.

The example below shows it working as intended, there must be a line to go down or up to.

**c#**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textbox.LineDown();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textbox.LineUp();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="88" Margin="87,94,0,0" Text="the old scamp went running through the park only to find the cat sitting in  a tree holding a bluejay in its mouth while a dog barked and circled below. tommy did not have time to give the dog  and cat an extra thought.  he was late for school" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinLines="5"/>
        <Button Content="line up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,103,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="line down" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You are correct. See my edit. (I had deleted the method, then recreated it for this question) I have two textboxes, one on top of the other to give the illusion of a text color change as you type. But I need to scroll the one behind when the user hits the bottom of the front one.

Comment: I can comment on my own answer at least.  It sounds like you are trying to make a chat or command interface.  Is that correct?  Simply put the reason LineUp won't work is the text box does not have another line below it.  You are going to have to transfer the text from the chat line into the back textbox first.

Comment: Don't comment inside an answer. Wait until you have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: How are WinAPI calls the answer to what does line up do?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.lineup(v=vs.110).aspx  It exists you can do it, you just must have a line below it which you did not.